# Example Composite Design Pattern - Genealogical Tree

Tags: design-patterns, composite, genealogy

I would like to model a genealogical tree with the composite pattern. For simplicity I am only interested:

to the marriage relationship between two people
to the paternity relationship between a parent and all her children.

For simplicity, it is not necessary to indicate any constraint on sex and number of parents.

How to adapt the Composite Pattern class diagram to this example?

Comment: Your diagram is wrong: a `Person` is not a `Genealogy`, neither is a `Union`

Comment: Learn to crop your screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram would look like this:

[image]